# How to properly read and write to a text file at the same time with multiple threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

On the main thread, I occasionally update my radios.txt file.  But then I have a background thread who's job is to read radios.txt file.  It reads radios.txt endlessly, on a loop.  Here is some code to illustrate....

Here is what gets executed on the main thread occasionally, at random times:

```
with open(radiosTxtFile, "wb") as fo:
            fo.write(json.dumps(theDevices))
```

Here is how I'm creating my background thread:

```
def read_radios():
    while True:
        read_devices()

def read_devices():
    with open(devicesFile, "rb") as file:
         theDevices = json.load(file)
         return theDevices

t = threading.Thread(name='radio_reader_thread', target=read_radios)
t.start()
```

I create my background thread and start it once the program launches.

I want to continue to use multiple threads to accomplish this, but what would be the proper way to do this?  It seems like using a Queue might be an appropriate route, but after reading up on them - I can't quite see how I would use it in this example.

Comment: The most basic synchronization thing is `Lock`. Why do not use it here?

Comment: I've never used Lock.  Looking it up now.  When using lock, what will happen if one thread is reading the file, and then the other tries to write with it?  Will it return an error?  Do you have a good example of how to implement Lock?

Comment: The second thread will waits untile the first one releases the lock. There are plenty numbers of lock usage examples in the net, just google them.